# Designing a user class - oop php

Tags: php, oop

ok. i am designing the classes in my application.

i have a User class. Now i need to list the users, get information about a particular user etc.

Initially what i tried  to do was this:

```
  class User
    {

    private $userId;
    private $name;
    private $age;

    function __construct()
    {
       // the code to get the user details from db and assign it to the properties.
    }

    // get the list of all the users
    public function getUserList()
    {
    }

    // add a new user
    public function addUser()
    {
    }

    // gets the username
    public function getUserName($userId)
    {
    return $this->name;
    }


}
```

These are my doubts:

1. Do you think it is a good idea to populate the properties from the database inside the
   constructor function? If not could you suggest a better way to do it?
2. Do the functions getUserList() and addUser() really belong to this class? or should i create a seperate class for getting user list, adding , deleting users and then another class for storing the information for a specific user? how should i go about designing this?

Thanks

Comment: Your domain objects should not care or even be aware of the database. You might wanna look into Data Mapper pattern: http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better option is to create two classes, Users and User.

```
class Users implements IteratorAggregate {
    /**
     * @return User[]
     */
    public function getUserList() {}

    public function addUser(User $user) {}

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser($userId) {}

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->getUserList());
    }
}

class User {
     public $userId;
     public $name;

     public function __construct() {}
}
```

Comment: What's the point of breaking encapsulation in `User` class?

Comment: @Jannis: could you tell me why you are using IteratorAggregate. what if i just directly call getUSerList() which returns an array?

Comment: @user1285659 You can foreach the class directly, like this: $list = new UserList(); foreach($list as $user) { }

Comment: @djay No point at all. The point was to demo how to write it as two classes instead of one. I was too lazy to write getters and setters ;)